# SESSION erase on Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, session

Here is the problem I have encountered for several days without solution:

On my website I use session variables to store errors when checking form server-side (PHP) that I display after a redirection on the page where the error occurred. I also use URL rewriting to change "page.php" to "page/" except for forms processing pages.

When I test the process locally everything works on all browsers. On the other hand when I pass on the hosted version (OVH) the session disappears, and only under chrome.

Has anyone ever encountered this problem and if so has it come to an end?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: Sounds like you may have something deleting the session cookie. Check for the `PHPSESSID` cookie in Chrome.

Comment: An extension such as [EditThisCookie](http://www.editthiscookie.com/) may help you track what's happening to the session cookie and its contents.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I check the PHPSESSID cookie and it's well defined but my $_SESSION variable is empty.